What is the lifecycle of an IHostedService/BackgroundService?
After StopAsync is called on an IHostedService, can StartAsync be called again on the same instance?
If so, this would imply that ExecuteAsync could be called more than once on the same BackgroundService instance.


After StopAsync is called on an IHostedService, can StartAsync be
called again on the same instance?

--Yes
a minimal Blazor server example:
public class MyBackGroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
 {
     private readonly ILogger<MyBackGroundService> _log;
     private Timer _timer;

     private int index { get; set; }


     public bool isRunning { get; set; }=false;
     public MyBackGroundService(ILogger<MyBackGroundService> log)
     {
         _log = log;
         index=new Random().Next(0,20);
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         _timer.Dispose();
     }

     public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         isRunning=true;
        
         _timer = new Timer(Do, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }

     public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         isRunning = false;
         _log.LogInformation($"{DateTime.Now} BackService{index} is Stopping");
         _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
     private void Do(object o)
     {
         _log.LogInformation($"Background Service{index} is working.  {DateTime.Now}");
         try
         {
             
             // dosometing 
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            
             _log.LogInformation("Error: {0}", e.Message);
             throw e;

         }
     }
 }

in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyBackGroundService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyBackGroundService>();

in razor component:
@inject MyBackGroundService backgroundservice;

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<button @onclick="start">Start</button>
<button @onclick="stop">Stop</button>




@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (backgroundservice.isRunning)
        {
            backgroundservice.StopAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
        }
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
    public void start()
    {
        if (!backgroundservice.isRunning)
        {
            backgroundservice.StartAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
        }

    }
    public void stop()
    {
        if (backgroundservice.isRunning)
        {
            backgroundservice.StopAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
        }

    }
}

The one registed as Singleton could start and stop for multipule times,the one registered with AddHostedService method would start when your app start,and stop when your app shut down
I clicked buttons follow the steps: start--stop--start,the console:


Thanks. I reason that there could be any number of different application hosts, and the documentation for IHostedService does not specify that StartAsync must only be invoked once, so we must assume that it could be. The fact that Microsoft's own application host does this adds weight to the idea that it's intentionally allowed.

To add to the accepted answer, this may not be something you have to design for depending where and how your service is deployed. I created a simple worker service, configured it with a Serilog file sink, and installed it as a Windows service on Windows 10.
public class Worker(ILogger<Worker> log) : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly Guid _instanceId = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Service starting. [{id}]", _instanceId);
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancel)
            .ConfigureAwait(ConfigureAwaitOptions.SuppressThrowing);
        log.LogInformation("Service stopping. [{id}]", _instanceId);
    }
}

This logs a different guid every time the service is started from the Services app. If this behavior is reliable, it simplifies things a lot because Worker can be injected with singletons instead of needing to manage instances scoped to ExecuteAsync.
